# Listening console.log

Tags: javascript, console, logging, devtools

I want to set a listener for `console.log()` and do something with the message without preventing the default behaviour. So, the console of the dev tools should get the message as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Never tried this in a webpage, but it work in a browser plugin (where javascripts rights are are not the same for security reasons).

You could definitively go for something like this :

```
(function(){

    var originallog = console.log;

    console.log = function(txt) {
        // Do really interesting stuff
        alert("I'm doing interesting stuff here !");

        originallog.apply(console, arguments);
    }

})();
```

The funny thing in javascript is that function are objects too :D

Comment: It seems that `console.log` can't work outside of the `console` object -- perhaps it relies on the `this` variable. Also, I don't consider having functions as objects funny: it's the thing that makes this language superb.

Comment: You are right ! I edited my answer. We will come to a great answer both of us ;)

Comment: The origin file name and line number are not kept in devtool with this approach.

Comment: How do you get the 'arguments' here? Seems to be undefined

Answer (score 4):

This is a small hack, but I'm not sure there is a better solution:

```
console._log_old = console.log
console.log = function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
    console._log_old(msg);
}
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it has side effect on the global scope. A better solution is to store console._log_old in a local variable in a closure instead of in the global scope.

Comment: Yes it will, using apply ;) See my edited answer. Thank for making this point anyway, that was true in the previous version and I didn't noticed that in the first place.