# Is it possible to trigger a jQuery event based on the browsers console log?

Tags: javascript

The following message appears in Firefox and Chrome when a track finishes playing in an iframe.

```
11:12:13.403: changestate PLAYING -> COMPLETED yahoo-dom-event_4491e143881eeb195e4dba0566c8d496.js:985
```

Is it possible to do trigger a jquery event when this message ("PLAYING -> COMPLETED") is logged?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000009/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-listen-console-events

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer in this case is no. Iframes that link to domains different from the main window are sandboxed for security reasons. You cannot get information into/out of them unless they have been explicitly set up to do so. The answer linked in the comments will not work because of these same security restrictions.

In this case, it would be up to BandCamp to expose that playing/completed information in a way that was externally available, which it appears they do not.