# Listen to browser console events and errors

Tags: javascript, console.log, developer-tools

Looking for a way to log on my server all console events shown on my visitor's browser console.
Not just what I'm firing with console.log, but everything...
Is there a way?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000009/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-listen-console-events

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way in JavaScript to listen console events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000009/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-listen-console-events)

Comment: Refer this: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000009/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-listen-console-events>

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can just override console method like

```
var logFn = console.log;

console.log = function(arg1) {
   // do your work on log information
   logFn('your console hacked')
}

console.error = function(arg1) {
       // do your work on error part
       logFn('your console hacked')
    }
```

you will find on console only one message 'your console hacked' you can customize according to you.