# Console.log listener

Tags: javascript, triggers, listener

I want to listen console texts in javascript and when something got wrong I will sent e-mail. I've created console.error, DOMError listener but it didn't work. I want to listen TypeError or SyntaxError in console screen. When something happened, I will run my code there.

I will listen this:
[image]

I found this topic about my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455631/listening-console-log) but this code doesn't work in my case.

```
(function(){ 
var originallog = console.log;
console.log = function(txt) {
    // Do really interesting stuff
    alert("I'm doing interesting stuff here !");
}})();
```

Comment: The alert worked in my console

Comment: Isn't it easier to fix the errors instead?

Comment: Thanks for interested @WashingtonGuedes For example I wrote console.log("blablabla") it runs the alert. My point is, I don't write something in console. It's like a DOM Error and I want to listen this one not console.log or console.error which I wrote.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes It may be easier but this code will help me where the problem is. It's a bit complicated. I need this :))

Comment: Can you even send an e-mail in Javascript, directly from a browser?? I don't think so. As @Washington said, why don't you... you know... fix the errors?

Comment: @JeremyThille Im working on a map-based project. I use Esri scripts and somewhere, somehow my objects get effected from something. I'm trying to find what effect my draw, snap objects. Console screen show me where the problem is but I don't know exact problem, I will use this method to find this. For example in a form I use draw object I draw a polygon with snapping, closed it then I edited my polygon and did something else. After some working, something effects my objects and I can't draw a polygon again.In the solution I will log where I clicked, what I draw or something and I will send mail

Comment: @JeremyThille sending email is not problem. if I can catch when an error occured my problem will be solved