# Getting the input from the console.log

Tags: javascript

How can I get the input from the console.log while using pure javascript?

For example I wrote "hello world" in the console - I would like to add an event listener which will check this input.

How should I do it?

Comment: I don't think this is even possible (the way you expect it to work). However, you can define a function with arguments and call it from console. Like "doSomething(your_input)".

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? It's trivial, but I don't really understand what value this would have.

Comment: Checkout the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455631/listening-console-log

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I would like to implement a basic easter egg on my web for developers. If user will write "egg" in the console.log it will move an image from one side to another of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an event listener, proxy the console itself:

```
interceptConsoleLog(fn) {
  const realLog = window.console.log;
  window.console.log = (function proxyLog() {
    // Do whatever you want the code to do, here.
    fn(...arguments); 

    // And then you fall through to the original log operation.
    realLog(...arguments)
  }).bind(console);
}
```

And then call it with your own handling function:

```
function doWhatever() {
  // ...
}

interceptConsoleLog(doWhatever);
```