# Detect a console.warn message

Tags: javascript

I have a need to find out when a warning (not error) message is sent to the browser's console.log . From research, I know that I can detect error messages with JavaScript code similar to this:

```
window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber){
    // any action you want goes here
    // errorMsg is the error message itself.
    // url should be the file presenting the error, though i have
    //    found that it only presents to me the address of the site.
    // lineNumber is the line number the error occoured on.
    // here is an example of what you could do with it:
    alert("Error in " + url + " at " + lineNumber + ":\n" + errorMsg);
}
```

But that only shows **error** messages. It will not show any **warning** messages.

Is there a similar way to detect a specific warning message in the console.log?  Or, alternately, is there some JS code that will allow me to search the console.log for a specific string?

Note that I can see the warning message in the browser's debugging (console logging) window. But I want to 'intercept' the warning message and perform some action if that warning is found.

**Added**

The intent is to find out when a specific warning message occurs; the message being similar to `"Loading failed for the <script> with source "https://www.example.com/js/somescript.js" .`

But the question of how to intercept a warning message (not error; the code I included does that) that is output by the browser (not my code).

**Added**

So, here's what I need. Assume this code

```
console.warn("Here is a warning!");
```

What code would you write to see if that message was written to the console as a warning?

Comment: Monkeypatch `console.warn`? Seems like quite an odd thing to do though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listening console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455631/listening-console-log)

Comment: Nope; that 'possible duplicate' doesn't answer my question of how to 'intercept' (or 'sense') a console.warn message, I believe.

Comment: dude you just override `console.warn` it's identical to post above except it's `console.log`

Comment: console.warn writes a warning message to the console. I need to intercept when a warning message is written. You can intercept console.logs with your own console.log function, but I haven't figured out how to look for a console.warn message. Creating your own console.log function doesn't do it, with my limited JS knowledge/testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warnings you are talking about are generated by the browser, not `console.warn`. This is why you cannot override it. Most likely, you need to manually add listeners for each event you need. For example, if you want to handle a script loading error use the `onerror` event:

```html
<script src="https://www.example.com/js/somescript1.js" onerror="console.log('Cannot load script from ' + this.src)"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/js/somescript2.js" onerror="console.log('Cannot load script from ' + this.src)"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about overriding the `console.log()`?

```js
let tmpConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = function(msg){
    // Intercept code goes here using msg variable
    alert(msg);
    // then perform the normal logging
    tmpConsoleLog(msg);
}

console.log("Something");
```

Comment: That seems to just do something when a console.log message is written. Although perhaps there could be code that would check if the msg is some string?

Comment: What do you mean? You can just put any interception code you want in the function instead of my alert() here.

Comment: True @holydragon, but I need to test when 'msg' contains a specific value. And I think that console.log only 'holds' error messages, not warning messages.

Comment: Do you mean `console.warn()`?

Comment: @RickHellewell You could simply replace all instances of `.log` in this code example with `.warn` and then replace the `alert(msg);` code with `if (msg === "ABC") { /* ... do something here */ } else { /* ... do something else. */ }`. It should be pretty easy to figure out. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's very late, but here's an answer that actually directly answers your question.

```js
var originalConsoleWarn = console.warn;
console.warn = function(message) {
  doSomethingWithWarn(message);
  originalConsoleWarn(message);
};

function doSomethingWithWarn(message){
  console.log("DOING SOMETHING WITH: " + message);
}

console.warn("hi");
```