# JS:Redirect/save web console message to a txt file

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to automatically save the messages displayed in the web console to a txt file using JS?
even using a browser configuration or other.
Thank you.

Comment: You could conceivably listen for `console.log()`'s and, when one occurs, derive a downloadable text file for the user. For this, since there is no log event, you would have to override `console.log()` with your own version. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6455713/1352288

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file  or you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19818659/11926970